# grant access to parts of repository to external company

Tags: git, git-svn, access-control

We're initiating new project in `Symfony2`. We would like to grant access to layouts and views folders for a third party who makes them for us, without revealing rest of the project.
Is this even possible? And simple?

I know that creating two repositories - one with code and one with layouts - could be a solution, but notice fact that in `Sf2` there are bundles, namespaces and lots of separate folders for views in many different places. Ending up in 20 repos or repository inception isn't a go.

for example (simplified):

```
(# in front marks shared folder)
web
config
#layouts
somestuff
modules
  - module1
      - controllers
      - models
      - #views
  - module2
      - controllers
      - models
      - #views
  - module3
      - controllers
      - models
      - #views
```

Comment: Could you isolate all those bundles, namespaces and so on in one repo though? One repo with a "public" vision of what needs to be shared?

Comment: Maybe yes, but I don't know how to do that ;)

Comment: Simply by making a branch in which you remove everything that isn't public. Then you push that branch to empty git repo, visible by the third-party contributors.

Comment: But what about merging it with base repo? Won't pull and merge delete those files in base repo?

Comment: pull and merge won't touch that extra branch. And you can merge back that branch anytime you want in the main branch, which is sync'ed back to svn.

Comment: That's git. Does this make a difference?

Comment: Sure you manage your extra branch in git (for commmunication with external contributors), but you merge what you want back in master, that you can `git svn debase` back in svn.

Comment: What are you using as a Git server? Some servers, e.g. [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite), have pretty granular access control that could really help in this situation.